# How to organize massive in php for getting separate massive for each item in one foreach loop?

Tags: php, foreach-loop-container

I made xpath query to url and get a collection of elements.
Now I need to get a collection of item's massives with massive for each item.
In recent code I have only one massive. Help me to organize massive correctly.

```
    //Queries by classNames
    $queryItem = $xpath->query('//div[@class="catalog__item"]');

    foreach ($queryItem as $goodsItem) {
        $result = array (
            "goodsItem" => array (
                    "queryName" => $xpath->query('//a[@class="goods__title"]', $goodsItem),
                    "queryPrice" => $xpath->query('//span[@class="price_block__cur-price"]', $goodsItem),
                    "queryDiscount" => $xpath->query('//span[@class="price_block__old-price"]', $goodsItem),
                    "queryImglink" => $xpath->query('//img[@class="catalog__item__image"]/@src', $goodsItem),
                    "queryDesription" => $xpath->query('//div[@class="catalog__item__text"]/p', $goodsItem)
                        )
            );
    }
    var_dump($result);
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `$result[] = array( ...`

Comment: Like this result
        array(
            array('name' => 'milk', 
                     'price' => 10),
            array('name' => 'meat', 
                     'price' => 20),
            array('name' => 'bread', 
                     'price' => 1),)

Comment: I improve my code by adding [ ] to $result. Now I get correct  collection of items. Now I onle need to get nodeValue for each item